# Call function every time the component becomes the active tab in react-native

Tags: react-native, navigation

I want to trig a function, each time the component becomes **active tab** in bottom navigation react-native. Can somebody give me a solution for this?

Comment: You can use https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#navigation-events or https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html

Comment: @SDushan thank you. But I did try those and the thing is, it only works once. Only when it initializes. I want to do this to a tab. Each time the tab gets active, I wanna trigger the function

Answer (score 8):

Use `focus` in [Navigation events](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#navigation-events) as below

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.focusListener = this.props.navigation.addListener('focus',
        () => alert('Screen focused'))
}
```

Make sure to remove the listener

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.focusListener.remove();
}
```

For extra information check below example

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";

class HomeScreen extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.focusListener = this.props.navigation.addListener("focus", () =>
      alert("Screen home")
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.focusListener.remove();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <Text>Home</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class SettingsScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <Text>Settings</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: Thanks again. But this only happens one time as the ``componentWillUnmount`` method never gets called when the active tab changes. And I'm using **BottomNavigation** from ``react-native-paper``

Comment: Yes Kavidu Aloka Kodikara, the Listener is added just one time, but it is triggered every time the screen becomes active.

Answer (score 0):

FOR TAB NAVIGATION TO REFRESH WHEN FOCUS USE THIS METHOD 100% WORKING.

this.focusListener = this.props.navigation.addListener('focus',
() => alert('Screen focused'))